Can you compost chametz in your backyard? If so, how?
Background
Some ways to get rid of food, from most to least environmentally-friendly, are:

Feeding it to animals.
Backyard composting.
Curbside municipal composting.
Burning it in a plastic bag.  Burning plastic releases hazardous fumes.  This is the worst choice.

Do not flush
Flushing food down your toilet is unwise.  It can clog your plumbing.  Or it can mix with cooking oil and "flushable" wipes, and can clog your city sewer.
Do not feed the birds
Bread can be deadly to some birds.  (Source.)
The situation
Non-frum PhD student Einat Kramer claims that, according to Modern Orthodox posek R' Yuval Sherlow, you can bury chometz in a composter three days before Pesach, instead of burning it.
I don't know whether this non-frum student is accurately citing R' Cherlow's entire ruling or not.  And, anyway, there are less than three days before Pesach.
Maybe you could make bread inedible, by mixing it with vinegar, earth, hot pepper flakes, and moldy food from your composter.  Perhaps you could make it so inedible that even a dog would ignore it.  Maybe then you could compost it.
But then again, maybe all this would be disrespectful to the bread.  Also, maybe you'd need to wrap the bread in newspaper before composting it.
My question
Is there any way you can compost chametz in your backyard, less than three days before Pesach?  If so, what are the steps?
Possibly related

Why don't people check their backyards for chametz?

Warning
Especially when it comes to severe prohibitions like chametz, please ask a rabbi yourself.
